# How to store a range of IP address (reserved and free) efficiently on database

Tags: sql, database, networking, ip, cloud

We have a cloud system, each customer have their own virtual network. Currently we have the list of network subnet assigned to each customer on DB.

They are stored in a network table with these columns:

```
| network      | ip_start | ip_end    | subnet_mask     |
```

New, we want to be able to let customer request individual IP(reserve). Customer can also free his IP when its no longer required.

Now I can think of creating a new table, storing all the already reserved IP.

When a new IP is requested, we will need to scan the new IP table to find a free IP within the corresponding network.

When a IP is being freed up, we will need to remove the IP record from the new table.

But this seems very slow and cumbersome, I m wondering if theres a better DB design for this.

**Adding more information**

Assuming we maintain the reserved IP table, I still can't think of a good way to find the next free IP.

Since there will be free IP sitting in the middle of the continuous range, to find these free IP, one will need to look up each IP and the next IP up to look for a gap.

Must I retrieve the whole range of IP from DB then search for the gap every time to get an free IP?

In additional, IPV6 must be supported in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the best design is to have a single row per IP.  If you are using IP-v4, then there are at most 4 billion-ish possibilities -- and your company does not own most of them.  This suggests something like:

```
|     network      | ip | reserved_by     | reserved_date
```

Having the *unavailable* ips will be very helpful for your environment, when it comes to reserving new addresses.  This is particularly true because you may have discontinuous ranges -- if not now, then as you become more successful and have to get more IP addresses.

You can also maintain a table, as you have described, using triggers or stored procedures to keep the two in-sync.

This solution may not be feasible for IPv-6, at least not at the finest level of granularity.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the design you suggested in the question except that, for better performance, you may want to store the IP a little differently. Each section could be left-padded with zeroes and then the entire IP could be converted to a BIGINT (using IPv4). This would allow for efficient use of an index using greater than and less than comparisons, and the "cumbersome" process of finding an unused IP could be implemented as finding the maximum value in the first contiguous set of IP's already used in the range and then incrementing by one. It would be helpful to have a function that would convert to and from the integer representation of the IP.

To be compatible with IPv6, you would not be able to convert to a BIGINT, so you could just leave it as a VARCHAR (or split into multiple ints). At that point, incrementing the IP by one would become less trivial, but still doable.

Either way, the strategy would be to pad the individual sections of the IP so that you could use indexes to make the process as efficient as possible.